# Programing the encoding function based on a decode RLE (bitwise) function

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Currently i only have the decoding procedure, **EncodedRle** is a byte array with the encoded image bytes, **pixel** is the pixel position to draw on decoded image, **col** is the decoded pixel color either 0 or 255, **matSpan** is the image pixel span (byte array)

**Decoding function:**

```
            int pixel = 0;
            foreach (var run in EncodedRle)
            {
                byte col = (byte) ((run & 0x01) * 255);

                var numPixelsInRun =
                    (((run & 128) > 0 ? 1 : 0) |
                     ((run & 64) > 0 ? 2 : 0) |
                     ((run & 32) > 0 ? 4 : 0) |
                     ((run & 16) > 0 ? 8 : 0) |
                     ((run &  8) > 0 ? 16 : 0) |
                     ((run &  4) > 0 ? 32 : 0) |
                     ((run &  2) > 0 ? 64 : 0)) + 1;
                
                for (; numPixelsInRun > 0; numPixelsInRun--)
                {
                    matSpan[pixel++] = col;
                }
            }
```

How can i write the Encoding function? I understand that i need to limit strides, so sum up equal pixels in same line up found a diferent value AND limiting to 128 max per byte? But i'm not good at bitwise and can't find a way to do it properly. And tips on that?

Comment: Is that bitwise "reverse" necessary?

Comment: Yes, otherwise i wouldn't care. Program must be able to decode and encode back